# How does angularjs handle csrf?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, csrf

I am having a bit trouble understanding the following code

```
run.$inject = ['$http'];

function run($http) {
  $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
```

as I always thought that csrf is injected into html forms or ajax calls and not cookie, since csrf is a protection against any adversary trying to use your cookie for authentication.

Can someone give a detail explanation on how angular is handling csrf and how does it get the token from the backend?

Comment: I believe you above code should lie inside `config` block instead of `run` block

Comment: I am not sure, but I found the code in this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial/)

Comment: thats ok but it should be inside config block..rather than run block

Comment: sorry if this is a noob question, but why should it be inside the config block?

Comment: configuration related setting should be always done inside `config` block, as it is standard pattern followed by all framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer this better than the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) themselves do, so I'll just quote:

> **Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection**
>
> XSRF is a technique by which an unauthorized site can gain your user's private data.
> Angular provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR
> requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default,
> XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). Since only
> JavaScript that runs on your domain could read the cookie, your server
> can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your
> domain. The header will not be set for cross-domain requests.
>
> To take advantage of this, your server needs to set a token in a
> JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on the first HTTP
> GET request. On subsequent XHR requests the server can verify that the
> cookie matches X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header, and therefore be sure that
> only JavaScript running on your domain could have sent the request.
> The token must be unique for each user and must be verifiable by the
> server (to prevent the JavaScript from making up its own tokens). We
> recommend that the token is a digest of your site's authentication
> cookie with a salt for added security.
>
> The name of the headers can be specified using the xsrfHeaderName and
> xsrfCookieName properties of either $httpProvider.defaults at
> config-time, $http.defaults at run-time, or the per-request config
> object.

The `$http.defaults.xsrfCookieName` is just allowing you to specify what the name of the cookie is, otherwise it's going to look for the default `XSRF-TOKEN`.

On the server side implementation, I'd recommend using some node.js middleware to handle the setting of the initial cookie instead of rolling your own. Take a look at [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) in particular as it seems to be the most popular. You could also try senchalab's [csrf](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html) middleware. Either of those ought to be enough to get you started.

Comment: can you provide an example? on django or nodejs?

Comment: @Kevin Did you try either of those node.js middleware I added to the answer?

Comment: I did but couldn't get the middleware to quite work, I need to do some more research on my own

Comment: @Mordred plz provide a example . i require a my application if can you provide example i use middle ware node js anf font use angular js .